# Android WebView caching

Tags: android, caching, webview

I am writing an app where the user is present with a list of URLs. To make it appear more faster, I want to detect the Wi-Fi state and load the URLs in the background, so when the user picks a URL, they are quickly presented the data specially when they are connected to Wi-Fi. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using [shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29). Which you can use to detect if you have a cached version of the requested URL and return an input stream to the cache which the WebView will use instead of loading it from ze webz

For versions before honeycomb, it might be possible to use [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), calling `webview.loadData(datafromcache, "text/html", "UTF-8");` and return true.

Comment: is there any code snippet which relates to cache ?

Comment: things have changed in the last 12 years, now its probably better to have trigger retrofit to pre-load the urls and then it'll have them cached (if configured) for later

Comment: thanks, my project is 10 years old so need to adapt accordingly. If any leads, let me know