# how to enable caching in webview android

Tags: android, caching, webview

I want to enable caching in webview android. I am loading an url in webview what I want is when I open the same url again in webview, it should load that url from cache in order to faster loading, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133591/android-webview-caching)

Comment: I have checked the above link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133591/android-webview-caching

But I do not know how to implement caching in webview, can you please guide me here.

Comment: Does the WebView do this automatically when the correct `Cache-Control` headers are set on the server? Would that work for you?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the WebView cache to enable caching in WebView.

In the properties of the WebView add the following line:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```